# How te get a percentage of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
user    result
john    +
mike    -
john    -
rita    +
```

I want to get the percentage of - grouped by user. So for my example the result must be:

```
user    %min
john    50%
mike    100%
rita    0%
```

Is that possible in mysql to create such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation.  Here is a simple method:

```
select user, avg(result = '-') as percent_min
from t
group by user;
```

This will give the result as a value between 0 and 1, which can then be formatted as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer implies a database platform that implicitly casts a Boolean TRUE to 1 and a Boolean FALSE to 0. Which is not prescribed by the standard. Should you run into an error going something like "Function avg(boolean) does not exist", try a CASE expression:

```
    WITH tb (usr,result) AS (
                  SELECT 'john','+'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'mike','-'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'john','-'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'rita','+'
    )
    SELECT 
      usr
    , AVG(CASE result WHEN '-' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS percent_min
    FROM tb
    GROUP BY usr
    ORDER BY usr;
```

Happy playing  -

Marco